# PDO breaks if the query returns an empty result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using [this page](http://www.thedevfiles.com/2014/08/moving-from-mysql-query-to-pdo/) to convert my queries from mysql to PDO, but it's breaking whenever the database query returns an empty result and gives this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in ...

This is the line that is producing the error:

`$Result =$db_val->query($Query)`
Were at that state the `$Query` is equal to "Select * from cms_roleassign WHERE rid='5' " and that returns nothing.

EDIT:
adding in some bit of the code where $db_val is initialized:

```
$db_val = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$config['DBHostName'].";database=".$config['DBName']
, $config['DBUserName']
, $config['DBPassword']);
```

Comment: `$db_val` is null. you didnt include any code above that so we cant tell you why.

Comment: @castis thanks for the comment, $db_val is not null and is working with queries that return data, but is not working with queries that doesn't return any results. Anyway I have added the bit of the code where I'm initializing the connection.

Comment: so if you're super sure that `$Query` contains a string, and you're super sure that **that** line threw the error. Then i'd double check to make sure that `$db_val` is indeed what you think it is. Is that line inside a loop by chance?

Comment: @castis It's not inside the loop but the function itself might be, I'll check. Thanks.